# NodeJS and SocketIO on Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a problem with my NodeJS and SocketIO setup on my server,
I want to access the HTTP Port by doing

var socket = io.connect("http://domain.com:8070");
Sadly this returns ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Here is my Server:

```
 var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: false })
  , fs = require('fs');

var mysocket = 0;
var socket = 0;
app.listen(8070);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/app/tpl/skins/habbo/client.php',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Client successfully connected'); 
  mysocket = socket;
});

//udp server on 41181
var dgram = require("dgram");
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
  console.log("Packet recieved from server: " + msg);
  if (mysocket != 0) {
     mysocket.emit('field', "" + msg);
     mysocket.broadcast.emit('field', "" + msg);
  }
});


server.on("listening", function () {
  var address = server.address();
  console.log("udp server listening " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});
server.bind(41181);
```

and my Client:

```
<script src="http://domain.com:8070/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var socket = io.connect(http://domain.com:8070);
            socket.on("hello", function(l){

                var k = l.split(/,/);
                switch(k){

                    case "testing":
                    {
                        window.alert('lol');
                        return;
                    }

                }
            });

        </script>
```

Any ideas on how I can get it to work on http://domain.com:8070? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your socket is not listening on port 8070.

Untested, but worth a try :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(8070), {log: false});
```

You can also remove the URL from your client (although it shoudn't change anything) :

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Edit :

You should also wrap the address in quotes :

```
var socket = io.connect("http://domain.com:8070");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it works on the serverip:8070
But I don't want to have my serverip shown in firebug for e.g

Comment: Can't you use localhost in this case?

Comment: and wrap the address in quotes